# In Linux, how do I find all files containing a string literal, even if the string is part of a compound word?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to find all of the documents/files in my linux folder and all folders within that folder (recursively) that contain the string "Apple". The problem is, my current grep statement **does not include 1Apple1 or AppleOrange** in my result set because it is part of a compound word that has additional numbers or letters.

Document fruits.txt is in /home/users/myUser/testing:

> apple
>   appleOrange
>   orange
>   Apple
>   1pear
>   1Apple1
>   @Apple (each on different lines)

This is my current grep statement:

> grep -rnwi '/home/users/myUser/testing' -e 'Apple'

Comment: grep -r Apple *

Comment: the `-w` option is causing your problem.  Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `grep -i "apple"`     `grep -i` is not case sensitive

this is an example :

[image]